# Test multiple file upload with jest nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, ts-jest

I am building an application with NodeJs where multiple files will be uploaded. Below is my test case and I am getting this error `Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MultipartValueSingle'.`

This is the test case

```
it('Create feed (POST)', () => {
        const video = path.resolve(__dirname, `../test-files/movie_video.mp4`);
        const image = path.resolve(__dirname, `../test-files/thumbnail.jpg`);
        const pdfDoc = path.resolve(__dirname, `../test-files/pdf_doc.pdf`);

        const multipleFiles : string[] = [video, image, pdfDoc]

        return request(app.getHttpServer())
            .post('/feed')
            .set('content-type', 'application/octet-stream')
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken)
            .field('text', 'Aenean imperdiet. Nam ipsum risus,. Curabitur suscipit suscipit tellus.')
            .field('payment_amount', 0)
            .attach('postDocs', multipleFiles)
            .expect(function (res) {
                if (!('message' in res.body) || !('payload' in res.body)) {
                    throw new Error('Response should contain message and payload.');
                } else if (res.body.message !== StatusMessages.Default) {
                    throw new Error('User not logged in');
                }
                if (!('user' in res.body.payload)) {
                    throw new Error('Payload should contain user.');
                }
                adminAccessToken = res.body.payload.access_token;
            });
    });
```

Comment: Docs says: `To send a file use .attach(name, [file], [options]). You can attach multiple files by calling .attach multiple times. `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is obvious, you should attach the multiple files by calling `.attach()` multiple times.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
import express from 'express';
import multer from 'multer';

const app = express();

const upload = multer();
const cpUpload = upload.fields([{ name: 'video' }, { name: 'image' }, { name: 'pdfDoc' }]);
app.post('/feed', cpUpload, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.files);
  console.log(req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

export { app };
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import path from 'path';
import request from 'supertest';
import { app } from '.';

describe('69663276', () => {
  it('Create feed (POST)', () => {
    const video = path.resolve(__dirname, `./movie_video.mp4`);
    const image = path.resolve(__dirname, `./thumbnail.jpg`);
    const pdfDoc = path.resolve(__dirname, `./pdf_doc.pdf`);

    const accessToken = '123';
    return request(app)
      .post('/feed')
      .set('content-type', 'application/octet-stream')
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken)
      .field('text', 'Aenean imperdiet. Nam ipsum risus,. Curabitur suscipit suscipit tellus.')
      .field('payment_amount', 0)
      .attach('video', video)
      .attach('image', image)
      .attach('pdfDoc', pdfDoc)
      .expect(200);
  });
});
```

test result:

```sh
 PASS  examples/69663276/index.test.ts (11.544 s)
  69663276
    ✓ Create feed (POST) (71 ms)

  console.log
    [Object: null prototype] {
      video: [
        {
          fieldname: 'video',
          originalname: 'movie_video.mp4',
          encoding: '7bit',
          mimetype: 'video/mp4',
          buffer: <Buffer >,
          size: 0
        }
      ],
      image: [
        {
          fieldname: 'image',
          originalname: 'thumbnail.jpg',
          encoding: '7bit',
          mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
          buffer: <Buffer >,
          size: 0
        }
      ],
      pdfDoc: [
        {
          fieldname: 'pdfDoc',
          originalname: 'pdf_doc.pdf',
          encoding: '7bit',
          mimetype: 'application/pdf',
          buffer: <Buffer >,
          size: 0
        }
      ]
    }

      at examples/69663276/index.ts:9:11

  console.log
    [Object: null prototype] {
      text: 'Aenean imperdiet. Nam ipsum risus,. Curabitur suscipit suscipit tellus.',
      payment_amount: '0'
    }

      at examples/69663276/index.ts:10:11

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.795 s
```